# how to uninstall VMware Workstation from Slackware64-current?

Tags: uninstallation, vmware-workstation, slackware

I'm trying to uninstall VMware-Workstation 7.x from Slackware64-current to install VMware-Workstation 8. When I run the bundle installer, it tries to uninstall version 7 before attempting to install version 8. But uninstallation process dies out. Since I've don't have version 7 installer at hand, I've attempted using the provided uninstall script with the following syntax as root:

> vmware-installer  --console --uninstall-component=vmware-workstation

It goes up 34% and closes. Then I try

> vmware-installer --list-components

And v.7 is still there!

Ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did your VMware display on pkgtool list view?
 #pkgtool

or you could try this link as a [reference](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-virtualization-90/vmware-workstation-7-1-2-cant-completely-uninstall-it-on-slackware-13-37-a-897724/#post4486274).

Regards,